# How to create RFC 2782-compliant SRV record with Terraform and AWS Service Discovery?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, service-discovery, terraform-provider-aws

I'm running a MySQL database in AWS ECS (*can't use RDS*), and I'd like to use [ECS Service Discovery](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/03/introducing-service-discovery-for-amazon-ecs/) to populate a SRV record which points to that database. I'm using Terraform to configure all AWS services.

This is what I have working so far ...

```
resource "aws_service_discovery_service" "mysqldb" {
  name = "mysqldb"
  health_check_custom_config {
    failure_threshold = 3
  }
  dns_config {
    namespace_id = "${aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace.stack_local.id}"
    dns_records {
      ttl  = "300"
      type = "SRV"
    }
    routing_policy = "MULTIVALUE"
  }
}

resource "aws_service_discovery_private_dns_namespace" "stack_local" {
  name        = "${var.stack_name}.local"
  description = "Testing with AWS Service Discovery"
  vpc         = "${aws_vpc.vpc.id}"
}
```

However, this creates a SRV record (`mysqldb.stack_name.local.`) that is not RFC 2782-compliant. In order to be compliant, it should include the service name and protocol, like this: `_mysql_._tcp.mysqldb.stack_name.local.`

I tried changing the name to something like `_mysql._tcp.mysqldb` but that failed because AWS requires the name to be a single label without any `.` in it.

Is it possible to create an RFC 2782-compliant SRV record using ECS Service Discovery with Terraform and the Terraform AWS provider?